# Create MFC DLL from C/C++ (VS 2010) code to be used by C# WCF web service

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a third party component written in C/C++ (on VS 2010) which can be downloaded [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3425260/thirdparty.cpp).

This component accepts 3 parameters as input (a filename and two numbers) and outputs a result in the console, and then outputs a file.

I've used Process and ProcessStartInfo in a C# WinForm project to consume this component which works fine. However, now I want to consume this in a WCF C# RESTful service, in which case the solution I thought with WinForm will not work.
It was suggested that I instead convert this to a MFC DLL and then use InterOp to call the unmanaged DLL through my C# web service (other suggestions are welcome).

Unfortunately, I have no idea on how to do that and my knowledge on C/C++ is fairly average. So my question is: How do I create a DLL from that component which accepts these 3 parameters (taken from main()):

```
    cin >> fname;
    cin  >> minA;
    cin  >> minO;
```

then does whatever calculations it's supposed to do and return this (again taken from main()):

```
cout << "\nNumber is: " << num;
```

(and obviously still output the file it's supposed to output) ?

Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: As a point of reference, here is my WinForm implementation mentioned above.

```
    ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    Process cmdProcess = new Process();
    BackgroundWorker BWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

//is able to report progress
    BWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    //is able to be cancelled
    BWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    //attach events
    BWorker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    BWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    BWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

  private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (firstTimeLoaded)
        {
            cmdStartInfo.FileName = Path.GetFullPath("../../Resources/thirdparty.exe");
            cmdStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetFullPath("../../Resources/");
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
            cmdProcess.SynchronizingObject = this;
            cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += cmd_Error;
            cmdProcess.Exited += cmd_Exited;
            cmdProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            cmdProcess.Start();
            cmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
            firstTimeLoaded = false;
        }
        while (!cmdProcess.HasExited)
        {
            if (use)
            {
                if (BWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                //read unbuffered output
                while (cmdProcess.StandardOutput.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    char inputChar = (char)cmdProcess.StandardOutput.Read();
                    if (inputChar != '\r' && inputChar != '\n')
                    {
                        builder.Append(inputChar);
                    }
                    if (inputChar == '\n')
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (cmdProcess.StandardOutput.Peek() == -1)
                {
                    cmdProcess.StandardOutput.DiscardBufferedData();
                }
                //process the output
                string output = builder.ToString();
                //determine appropriate action
                switch (output)
                {
                    case "Enter file name: ":
                        cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
                        break;
                    case "Enter minimum size of A: ":
                        cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
                        break;
                    case "Enter minimum size of O: ":
                        cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(textBox3.Text);
                        break;
                }
                if (output.Contains("Number: "))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Number is: " + output.Substring(output.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1));
                    use = false;
                }         

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you going to consume the service, from another .NET application or do you need it to be more standard?

Comment: Hi Eddie Paz, are you talking about the DLL? It will be used from a C# RESTFul WCF web service.

Comment: OK, you should create a Win32 DLL with an exported function that returns the "numcons" and it accepts the input fields. You then create a C# library that calls the Win32 DLL through InterOp. Accomplishing that, you're set to move to creating the service.

Comment: Hi Eddie, thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate a bit further, i.e. how to create such a file, some online documentation/examples?

Comment: Are you able to modify and compile the .cpp file you referenced? You obviously have it, but it may be part of a library you don't compile. This is pretty involved and custom. I wish I could give you links that could walk you thru, but I'll help you as much as I can.

Comment: Hi, yes the .cpp file runs and compiles normally through Visual C++ and is not a part of any library.

Comment: In your winform project, how are you feeding the fname, minIn, and minEx to the console app/cpp file?

Comment: Hi Eddie, I've updated the original post to demonstrate the WinForm implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's give this a try.

1. In VS2010, create a Win32 Project under Visual C++/Win32. For this purpose, call it MyWin32Lib.
2. Add the thirdparty.cpp file to the project and compile. You should get some warnings, but it's ok.
3. Create a new header file called thirdparty.h so we can export the function signature.
4. In the thirdparty.h file, do:

   ```
   #pragma once
   // This will be the interface for third party file
   int concepts(char* szFileName, int nMinIntent, int nMinExtent);
   ```
5. In the thirdparty.cpp file, add #include "stdafx.h" right before #include
6. Change the main function signature to match the one in the header:

   ```
   //int main()
   // Instead of getting input from console, we're passing it the values
   int concepts(char* szFileName, int nMinIntent, int nMinExtent)
   ```
7. Comment out all input requests, and just copy the args to the local vars:

   ```
   //cout << "\n\n***** In-Close 3.0 Concept Miner *****";
   //cout << "\n\nEnter cxt file name including extension: ";
   //cin >> fname;
   //cout << "\nEnter minimum size of intent (no. attributes): ";
   //cin  >> minIn;
   //cout << "\nEnter minimum size of extent (no. objects): ";
   //cin  >> minEx;

   strcpy_s(fname, _countof(fname), szFileName);
   minIn = nMinIntent;
   minEx = nMinExtent;
   ```
8. Comment out cout << "\nNumber... (this is no longer needed)
9. At the end of the function, do:

   ```
   break;
   }

   //cout << "\n\nHit <enter> to finish";
   //while ( !_kbhit());

     return numcons;
   }
   ```

*I don't know why there's a while(1) since there's no way to get out of it, but assume we'll doing it only once.*

1. Make sure you compile ok.
2. Create a new CPP file, call it "Concepts.cpp"
3. In Concepts.cpp, enter:

   ```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include "thirdparty.h"

   extern "C"
   {
       __declspec(dllexport) int GetConcepts(char* szFileName, int nMinIntent, int nMinExtent)
       {
         return concepts(szFileName, nMinIntent, nMinExtent);
       }
   }
   ```

*You should now have a Win32 DLL that performs the work using arguments instead.

1. Create a C# Class Library project.
2. Create a C# class called "Concepts.cs"
3. In this class, enter:

   ```
   public class Concepts
   {
     // Link to the Win32 library through InterOp
     [DllImport("MyWin32Lib.dll")]
     public static extern int GetConcepts(
       [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )] string fileName, int minIntent, int minExtent );
   }
   ```

*You have to marshal the filename input as ANSI since that's what thirdparty.cpp uses.

I think I got all of it. You can now reference your C# library from a web service.

Comment: Hi Eddie, thanks for taking the time into it. I've started implementing your guide and will get back to you. P.S: the while(1) is not actually needed, I'll remove it.

Comment: I apologize the code did not format properly. I slightly hate this editor. :)

Comment: No problem, I can handle it ;)

Comment: Hi Eddie, I've implemented all your steps: created MyWin32Lib, created C# Class Library project, added that library to my project and tried this code:  int num = Concepts.GetConcepts(textBox1.Text, int.Parse(textBox2.Text), int.Parse(textBox3.Text)); But I get this error: "Unable to load DLL 'MyWin32Lib.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)". The C# Class Library Project compiled fine though. What am I missing here?

Comment: You have to make sure that the MyWin32Lib.dll is in the same directory as your C# library, otherwise it won't be found. In your C# Library project, go to Properties and add a Post-build event to copy the DLL for you: copy <path>MyWin32Lib.dll $(OutDir)

Comment: Ok so now I made sure that both the DLLs (C# DLL and C++ DLL) are in the same dir and tried reexecuting. I get a different error now: System.DllNotFoundException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to load DLL 'MyWin32Lib.dll': Not enough storage is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)

Comment: I should also note that I'm running this on both 1) locally: 4core with 8GB RAM 2) remotely: 64core with 256GB RAM --> same error on both machines

Comment: It's probably inside the while loop and never gets out. Make sure the function returns properly.

Comment: Well I removed the while loop from the first time :/

Comment: It's missing your modified thirdparty.cpp though so can't compare with mine to see what's not working :)

Comment: Eddie, it's official. You are THE MAN. I honestly do not have words to thank you enough!! :)

Comment: One final question, although not crucial: you'll notice there are some custom exit codes in the .cpp, is it easy to catch them? They're there on purpose.

Comment: Right below char fname[100], create a new global int, say exitcode. In all sections where exit(?) is call, store the code in the global int and comment out the exit. Before you return numcons, check the exitcode for != 0, if so, return exitcode * -1. That way if the function returns < 0 you know the exit code, if positive, it's the value. Since exit ends the app, you may not want to continue, so throw an exception instead and catch it in concepts before returning. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Download http://www.eddiepaz.com/thirdparty.zip again. I changed it to catch the exception, but did not replace all "quits".

Comment: Yup, makes perfect sense :) Once again, you have my uttermost gratitude, I honestly have no words. I wish there were more like you and you officially are one of my role models.