# System.DllNotFoundException in .NET DLL

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I took a program written in C/C++ and modified it's main function to accept some arguments as input and return a variable as output and created a Win32 DLL out of it. I then created a .NET DLL which uses InterOp to access the first DLL. Now when I load the .NET DLL in my C# app I get a System.DllNotFoundException from the DLL which is really baffling me as there were never memory issues with the program and both Win32/.NET dlls are located in the same directory (apart from modifying the main function, the code has not really changed).
The solution was provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849278/create-mfc-dll-from-c-c-vs-2010-code-to-be-used-by-c-sharp-wcf-web-service) thread, which was my original question some time ago. I'm pretty sure that answer is correct but I'm just missing something.

You can download my VS solution [Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3425260/LibClose.rar). The solution contains three projects: the Win32 DLL, the .NET DLL, and a winform app that references the .NET DLL (but when trying to test gives the DLL exception). Any help or debugging guidance would be greatly appreciated.

- UPDATE: I have tried all the tips/suggestions below but I still get the exact same error. If it makes things easier, my VS solution is available to download in the hyperlink above.

Comment: Make sure the native DLL is copied into the same directory as your EXE and that all of its dependencies (like the CRT) are installed as well.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon if you have no idea what might be missing.

Comment: @HansPassant if you download the VS project you will notice that the C# app contains both dlls and exe in the same folder. By the way, I get the same error on my Windows 7/8 machines and on Windows Server

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have placed the win32 dll on /windows/system32 folder(if only the dll name is passed to DllImport)

Alternatively you can also pass the full path of the dll to the DllImport Attribute.

Use a tool such as [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to make sure you are not missing out on any dependent assembly.

Comment: I'm using [DllImport("LibCloseWin32.dll")] which is located in the same folder as the .NET DLL, is that not sufficient?

Comment: use dependency walker to see if ur missing any dependencies

Comment: ur native dll LibCloseWin32.dll

Comment: find and place ntdll on system32 folder